# How to properly store a previously serialized Json document (not POJO) into DynamoDB?

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

AWS has published an article titled **[Storing JSON In Amazon DynamoDB Tables](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/storing-json-documents-in-amazon-dynamodb-tables/)**, unfortunately, this document does not describe *how to store JSON in Amazon DynamoDB Tables*: it describes how to *store an Annotated Java POJO*, which is an entirely different animal, in Amazon DyamoDB tables.

How do you store an actual JSON document, previously serialized into a `java.lang.String`, into DynamoDB, in a manner that properly represents the JSON structure as Dynamodb Attributes?

"Proper representation" here means that storing the whole serialized Json into a single DynamoDB String field does not qualify as an answer to this question.